# Cant deploy using meteor mup to aws ec2 Error: Try reinstalling node-fibers

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, meteor-up

I cant deploy to aws using mup in meteor. I manage to setup success just cant deploy. I got the `Error: Try reinstalling node-fibers`. my node version is v.0.10.40. I have set my `deployCheckWaitTime` to as long as 300 and it still doesnt work.

mup.json

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      "pem": "web.pem"
    }
  ],

  "setupMongo": true,
  "setupNode": true,
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.40",
  "setupPhantom": true,
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  "appName": "WebApp",
  "app": "../WebApp",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/WebApp"
  },

  "deployCheckWaitTime": 60
}
```

This is what i get from mup logs

> Error:
>   `/opt/WebApp/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node`
>   is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
>       at Object. (/opt/ArcWeb/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16:8)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/opt/WebApp/app/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8 [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] error: Script
>   restart attempt #63

From terminal

```
Started TaskList: Deploy app 'WebApp' (linux)
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] - Uploading bundle
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] - Setting up Environment Variables
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] - Invoking deployment process
[xx.xxx.xxx.xx] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/ArcWeb/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
    Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    ting
    ansi-regex@0.2.1 node_modules/ansi-regex

    ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles

    chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk

    escape-string-regexp@1.0.3 node_modules/escape-string-regexp

    has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi

    strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi

    supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color

    eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline

    type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of

    amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine

    asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap

    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    meteor-promise@0.5.0 node_modules/meteor-promise

    promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise

    source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support

    semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

    source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map

    fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
    connected
    WebApp stop/waiting
    WebApp start/running, process 21718
    Waiting for 60 seconds while app is booting up
    Checking is app booted or not?
    WebApp stop/waiting
    WebApp start/running, process 21894
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```